How to use AutomationElement in a .NET Core 8 console application?
I'm working on a console application using .NET Core 8 and I need to use the AutomationElement object from the UIAutomation library to automate UI tasks.
I've used AutomationElement in .NET Framework applications before, but I'm facing issues using it in a .NET Core 8 console application. I'm not sure which packages to install or how to reference the necessary assemblies.
Environment details:

.NET Core 8
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2022

I tried installing various UIAutomation-related NuGet packages, but none seem to provide the AutomationElement class for .NET Core 8. I've also looked for any documentation or examples specific to .NET Core but haven't found anything helpful.

Edit the project file and add <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>

You can't find it because the AutomationElement is part of the System.Windows.Automation namespace, and that namespace/class is not compatible with or available in .NET 8. This is taken from the page for that class in the .NET API Browser:



Product
Versions




.NET Framework
3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8, 4.8.1


Windows Desktop
3.0, 3.1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9



You'll need to look into a different UI automation library that is compatible with .NET 8.
(By the way, it's not called .NET Core 8. It's just .NET 8. Core is obsolete now, despite the name appearing in other frameworks like EntityFramework Core. If you've been searching using the word "Core" you might have been limiting your results.)

@Omar Don't forget to upvote answers that are helpful. This site is built on the voting system. And if this answer has sufficiently answered your question please consider marking it as accepted as well. I prefer to wait a day or two before doing that in case someone else posts a better one though.
